# App Center build fails with no error messages

Tags: visual-studio-app-center

I recently renamed my App Center organization and since then all builds are failing immediately with no error messages.

[image: app center build failed screenshot]

I can't open the logs either (I tried multiple apps).
[image: unzip error screenshot]

Any clues?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue reproducing after changing the name of the application in AppCenter. What magically solved my issue was to enter the configure build screen and click save&build. Worth mentioning that I did not change the configuration I previously had. I reckon this is not a technical answer, but it solved my problem, since I didn't know where to start debugging the issue.

Comment: My issue occurred when moving an existing application from one organization to another. Your solution helped with that as well.